# Creating GUID by Python from bytes

Tags: java, python, uuid

I get a mission to create the following GUID:

The code in Java should be like this:

GUID ==> java.util.UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(username.getBytes());

I would like to do the same computation given a username and to receive the same GUID in Python!

I did the following but did not manage to get the same GUID:

```
def compute_guid_by_username(username):
    bytes = get_bytes(username)
    class NULL_NAMESPACE:
        bytes = b''

    guid = uuid.uuid3(NULL_NAMESPACE, bytes)
    return guid
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the 'get_bytes' function. When I run your code without that bit, it works just fine.

Without the 'get_bytes' function:

```
import uuid

def generate_guid(username):
    class NULL_NAMESPACE:
        bytes = b''

    guid = uuid.uuid3(NULL_NAMESPACE, username.encode('utf-8'))
    return guid
```

Trying it out:

```
In [1]: from guids import generate_guid

In [2]: generate_guid('bob')
Out[2]: UUID('9f9d51bc-70ef-31ca-9c14-f307980a29d8')

In [3]: generate_guid('bob')
Out[3]: UUID('9f9d51bc-70ef-31ca-9c14-f307980a29d8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code worked for me -

```
import uuid;

def generate_guid(username):

    class NULL_NAMESPACE:
        bytes = b''

    guid = uuid.uuid3(NULL_NAMESPACE, username);
    return guid
```

---

thanks,
Murty